# RadComboBox selects first item on Textchanged

Tags: wpf, combobox, telerik

I have a radcombobox which is TextSearchEnabled and Editable. The issue is whenever there is a textchanged it automatically selects the first item that is matched and that actually filters out the other dropdown which i wanted to restrict it.

Is there anyway i can restrict this behavior and only update the selected item on lost focus.

```
     <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="ComboBox"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" 
                          SelectAllTextEvent="GotFocus"
                          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                          IsEditable="True"
                          telerik:TextSearch.TextPath="FullName"
                          IsFilteringEnabled="True"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"
                          TextSearchMode="Contains"
                          MinWidth="80"
                          DisplayMemberPath="FullName"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer from telerik forum where i posted the same question. So here i am answering it on my own.

**ANSWER:**

> In order to disable the auto selection of items in the RadComboBox
>   control all you need to do is set its **CanAutocompleteSelectItems**
>   property to False.

Here's the link to forum:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/combobox/radcombobox-selects-first-item-on-textchanged.aspx